# Why the mapping/coordinates/size have no effect on displacement modifier texture?

Tags: texture-coordinates

I am coming from 3ds max and spent all night long trying to understand how the texture mapping work specially when use in the displacement modifier.

When i adjust the texture size in mapping only the image change and not the displacement.

I know there is another tab call image mapping where i can change the size of the texture but it is less convenient than the mapping tab where i can scale the texture in the negative.

Here a gif to explain it more precisely :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me that you are trying to modify the material texture not the modifier texture as they are not the same for blender. I am no blender internal expert though

[image]

Comment: if you go in material mode or render view you will probably see the changes when you increase the texture size

Comment: I can see the texture and change it with mapping when i use the rendered viewport mode but i don't understand why it doesn't work in regular texture view.

Comment: if you are still referring to the displacement modifier it is probably because you are in wrong tab. if you are, instead, referring to the Show World Texture texture coordinate, I honestly don't remember what was its purpose.. its been a long time since I used blender internal. One note though.. you may not know that Blender Internal is currently being deprecated from the next major update (2.80).. so unless you have a particular good reason of using it you just better off learning Cycles or EEVEE.

Comment: Hi Virgil you are right about blender internal but i was just curious why it didn't work because i came from 3ds max and tiling texture is something that work even with max internal renderer. I found it was strange that the tiling work only on the image and not on the displacement. Thank for your time and explanations.